# Python 2: What is wrong with this else/if statement. always receiving same output

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

So, I Am trying to create some code, and for whatever reason the following always gives the same output, "Great! let's continue"

I am fairly new programmer, so any explanation has about why this is happening and how I can fix it is welcome. Thank you!

```
#python 2
UserAnswer = raw_input('Is your age and birthday correct? (yes/no):')
if UserAnswer == 'yes' or "Yes":
   print ("Great! let's continue.")
elif UserAnswer == 'no' or "No":
  print("check for your error, the program will now end")
  SystemExit
else:
   print 'Invalid input.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line will always evaluate to `True`:

```
if UserAnswer == 'yes' or "Yes"
```

This is because "Yes", when treated as a boolean, evaluates to True. So the result of the OR will be True. You can fix it by changing it to the following (and do the same thing for the other line)

```
if UserAnswer == 'yes' or UserAnswer == 'Yes'
```

Comment: would be even easier to do `if UserAnswer.lower() == 'yes':`

Comment: I was going to suggest the same.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do:

```
if UserAnswer == 'yes' or "Yes":
```

Do instead:

```
if UserAnswer == 'yes' or UserAnswer == "Yes":
```

Same applies to the `elif` condition